# Java (prior to JDK8 update 131) applications running in docker container CPU / Memory issues?

Tags: java, docker, jvm, cgroups

JVM's  (JDK 8 before Update 131) running in docker containers were ignoring the CGroup limitations set by the container environment.
And, they were querying for host resources  and not what was allocated to the container.
The result is catastrophic for the JVM  i.e As the JVM was trying to allocate itself more resources (CPU or Memory)  than what is permitted through CGroup limits, docker demon would notice this and kill the JVM process or the container itself if the java program was running with pid 1.

**Solution for memory issue -**  (possibly fixed in JDK 8 update 131)
Like described above, JVM was allocating it's self more memory than what's allowed for the container. This could be easily fixed by

1. explicitly setting the max heap memory limit (using `-Xmx` ) while starting the JVM.  ( prior to 131 update)
2. or by passing these flags -  (after 131 update)
   `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions`    and
   `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap`

**Resolving the  CPU issue** (possibly fixed in JDK update 212 )
Again like described above, JVM running in docker would look at the host hardware directly and obtain the total CPUs available. Then it would try to access or optimize based on this CPU counts.

1. After JDK 8 update 212,  any JVM running in  docker container will respect the cpu limits allocated to container and not look into host cpus directly.
   If a container with cpu limitation is started as below, JVM will respect this limitation and restrict itself to 1 cpu.
   `docker run -ti --cpus 1 -m 1G openjdk:8u212-jdk`   //jvms running in this container are restricted to 1cpu.
2. **HERE IS MY QUESTION:** The CPU issue is probabily fixed in JDK8 Update 212, **but what if I can not update my JVM and I am running version prior to update 131 , how can I fix the cpu issue.**

Comment: You tagged this with "docker"; it should be extremely straightforward to update the `FROM` line in your image and re-run `docker build` to upgrade the JVM.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I appreciate your solution. But this is not a option I have. I have already mentioned this as one of the solutions. Please re-read the question. I know that upgrading to 212 in the docker image might fix it. But for internal reasons I can't go beyond update 131 and has to find a solution for JVM's prior to 131. That is the Question.

Comment: @DavidMaze, other way said, I can't touch/change the image or jdk version in docker. At best, I can change the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` i.e pass arguments to the jvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux container support first appeared in JDK 10 and then ported to 8u191, see [JDK-8146115](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146115).

Earlier versions of the JVM obtained the number of available CPUs as following.

- Prior to 8u121, HotSpot JVM relied on `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)` libc call. In turn, glibc read the system file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/online`. Therefore, in order to fake the number of available CPUs, one could replace this file using a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/):

  ```
  echo 0-3 > /tmp/online
  docker run --cpus 4 -v /tmp/online:/sys/devices/system/cpu/online ...
  ```

  To set only one CPU, write `echo 0` instead of `echo 0-3`
- Since 8u121 the JVM became [taskset aware](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6515172). Instead of `sysconf`, it started calling `sched_getaffinity` to find the CPU affinity mask for the process.

  This broke bind mount trick. Unfortunately, you can't fake `sched_getaffinity` the same way as `sysconf`. However, it is possible to replace libc implementation of `sched_getaffinity` using [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick).

I wrote a small shared library [proccount](https://gist.github.com/apangin/78d7e6f7402b1a5da0fa3abd93811f36) that replaces both `sysconf` and `sched_getaffinity`. So, this library can be used to set the right number of available CPUs in all JDK versions before 8u191.

**How it works**

1. First, it reads `cpu.cfs_quota_us` and `cpu.cfs_period_us` to find if the container is launched with `--cpus` option. If both are above zero, the number of CPUs is estimated as

   ```
   cpu.cfs_quota_us / cpu.cfs_period_us
   ```
2. Otherwise it reads `cpu.shares` and estimates the number of available CPUs as

   ```
   cpu.shares / 1024
   ```

   Such CPU calculation is similar to how it actually works in a modern container-aware JDK.
3. The library defines (overrides) `sysconf` and `sched_getaffinity` functions to return the number of processors obtained in (1) or (2).

**How to compile**

```
gcc -O2 -fPIC -shared -olibproccount.so proccount.c -ldl
```

**How to use**

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libproccount.so java <args>
```

Comment: appreciate the detailed explanation. Thx.   `Linux container support first appeared in JDK 10 and then ported to 8u191` - got it.  (1) But does not this beat the whole point of namespaces and cgroups. (2) from wiki - `cgroup namespace type has existed since March 2016 in Linux 4.6`. So what is the point of this new cgroup namespace. Why should applications i.e JVM care about adding container support - docker engine i.e `containerd` should do i.e provide the isolation by default. Bit difficult to wrap the head around this ????

Comment: @RedwinD It provides *isolation*, but not *virtualization*.

Comment: your post answers my Q. thx. But the Technology itself seems to be unclear or confusing..

Comment: quote from wiki - `OS-level virtualization is an operating system paradigm in which the
kernel allows the existence of multiple **isolated** user space instances.`  - like you said it uses the word `isolated` not `virtualisation`. So agree with you on this. But the article itself is about - [OS-level virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS-level_virtualization)

Comment: next - the same article says, `A computer program running on an ordinary operating system can see all resources (connected devices, files and folders, network shares, CPU power, quantifiable hardware capabilities) of that computer. However, **programs running inside of a container can only see the container's contents and devices assigned to the container.**` - just want to confirm is this abstraction or virtualization.

Comment: finally - [Should applications (like those developed in C ) add container (say docker) support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64312354/should-applications-like-those-developed-in-c-add-container-say-docker-supp)